# Switching desktop managers from the command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, gdm, fvwm

I run the `fvwm` desktop window manager on Ubuntu 18.04, but sometimes I need to switch to `ubuntu`.     The standard way to do this is to log out, select `ubuntu` at the login screen and relog in.     But then, `ubuntu` becomes the default, and I have to manually switch back, at the login screen.     What I'd like to do is this:  before logging out of `fvwm` run a command line script that changes the default manager to `ubuntu`, then once I'm in `ubuntu`, run another command that switches the default manager back to `fvwm`.      This forum says: install `gdm` and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`;   this would be better than nothing, but it's still a `gui`; however, `gdm` isn't on my system and I can't seem to install it.

So my question is:  can I do this from the command line, and if not, how can I find `gdm` or some equivalent that runs on `18.04`

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Comment: "Sometimes I have to grit my teeth and switch to `ubuntu`." - Why? I sense a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here.

Comment: FVWM is a desktop **window** manager. It isn't a desktop manager.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I find gdm or some equivalent that runs on 18.04

gdm3 is the package you want. There are also other display managers that offer switching of sessions such as lightdm which is a lightweight alternative to GNOME's gdm3 and KDE's sddm.

Also lightdm allows [switching of the default session from the CLI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Change_the_Default_Session) which you could automate via a script when you log into the Ubuntu session.

Comment: I think the OP has already set up a display manager. Quote: "The standard way to do this is to log out, select ubuntu at the login screen and relog in." His problem is that the last selected session becomes the default.